# display ssh2 stdout and stderr in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ssh

I'm building a node.js application to manage servers.
In this application, I can create some shell scripts and execute them on a server by clicking on a button.

Here is what I have in my routes.js file for this action :

```
app.get('/exec', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {

  var url = require('url');
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = url_parts.query;

  var Server         = require('../app/models/server');
  var Script         = require('../app/models/script');
  var async          = require('async');
  var scriptId       = query.scriptId;
  var userId         = query.userId;
  var serverId       = query.serverId;

  var stdout = "";
  var stderr = "";

  async.parallel({
    servers: function(callback){
      Server.find({"_id" : serverId}).exec(callback);
    },
    scripts: function(callback){
      Script.find({"_id" : scriptId}).exec(callback);
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

      var selectedServer = results.servers;
      var selectedScript  = results.scripts;

      var serverIp       = selectedServer[0].serverDetails.serverAddress;
      var serverPort     = selectedServer[0].serverDetails.serverPort;
      var serverUsername = selectedServer[0].serverDetails.serverUsername;
      var scriptContent  = selectedScript[0].scriptDetails.scriptContent;

      var Connection   = require('ssh2');
      var conn         = new Connection();
      conn.on('ready', function() {
        //console.log('Connection :: ready');
        conn.exec(scriptContent, function(err, stream) {
          if (err) throw err;
          stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            //console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
          }).on('close', function() {
            //console.log('Stream :: close');
            conn.end();
          }).on('data', function(data_out) {
            console.log('STDOUT: \n' + data_out);
            stdout = stdout + data_out;
            res.render('execresults.ejs', {
              stdout : stdout
            });
          }).stderr.on('data', function(data_err) {
            console.log('STDERR: \n' + data_err);
          });
        });
      }).connect({
        host: serverIp,
        port: serverPort,
        username: serverUsername,
        privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('id_rsa')
      });

      conn.on('error', function(e) { console.log("Connection failed or timed out")});

    });

  });
```

It works fine and I have the results of the execution in the console. But I would like to display both stdout and stderr results in two textarea of an ejs page.

The problem is that when I run a simple command like "uptime", it works, I will have the stdout result displayed in my textarea.

But when the shell script returns both stdout and stderr, or if stdout is a large amount of text, I don't have everything passed to my ejs page because of this error I think : *Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.*

My question is : How can I send both stdout and stderr to my ejs page, only when the script is completely executed ? I tried to build a "stdout" variable by concatenating all stdout output but it doesn't seem to work...

Can someone help me ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the process eventually ends on its own and it does not output a lot of data, you could probably just buffer the data and then render when the process closes:

```
conn.exec(scriptContent, function(err, stream) {
  if (err)
    return res.send(err);

  var stdout = '',
      stderr = '';
  stream.on('close', function() {
    conn.end();
    res.render('execresults.ejs', {
      stdout: stdout,
      stderr: stderr
    });
  }).on('data', function(data) {
    stdout += data;
  }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    stderr += data;
  });
});
```

Secondly,

```
if (err)
  res.send(err);
```

should really have a `return`:

```
if (err)
  return res.send(err);
```

to prevent further execution on errors.

Comment: Dear ssh2 creator, thanks a lot it works perfectly :) ! I would like to ask you something : Is this way the best way to execute a shell script on a server, or is it better to upload the script using sftp and then exec the script ? thanks alot !

Comment: I don't think there is a "best way," it all depends on your needs and what works best for you. I mean, if the script is not static, then I don't think it's worth doing an upload, calling exec, then deleting the file off the server. If it's a script that never changes, then just uploading it once and calling it in exec might be more favorable since you're transmitting less bytes (but if it's a small script that's probably a negligible performance hit). Either way you're getting the same output.